# LibGit2Sharp Fetch On a Cloned Repository fails

Tags: c#, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I have a local repository `cloned` from a remote repo.

I do a `Fetch` and it throws the below exception:

> An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Reference (Error). Target
>   OID for the reference doesn't exist on the repository

**Stack Trace For the exception:**

```
at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.HandleError(Int32 result) in D:\Personal\Projects\LibGitSharp\libgit2sharp\LibGit2Sharp\Core\Ensure.cs:line77
at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.ZeroResult(Int32 result) in D:\Personal\Projects\LibGitSharp\libgit2sharp\LibGit2Sharp\Core\Ensure.cs:line 96
at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_remote_update_tips(RemoteSafeHandle remote) in D:\Personal\Projects\LibGitSharp\libgit2sharp\LibGit2Sharp\Core\Proxy.cs:line1435
```

**This is my code:**

```
    public void Fetch()
    {
        var remote = this.LibGit2SharpRepo.Network.Remotes.FirstOrDefault();
        if (remote != null)
        {
            this.LibGit2SharpRepo.Fetch(remoteName:"origin");
            //TODO : Soft reset to the latest commit
        }
    }

    private IRepository _libGit2SharpRepo;
    public IRepository LibGit2SharpRepo
    {
        get { return _libGit2SharpRepo ?? (_libGit2SharpRepo = new Repository(this.RepositoryPath)); }
    }
```

Also, my remote repo is also on my local disk

```
[remote "origin"]   
fetch = +refs/heads/\*:refs/remotes/origin/\*   
url = D:\\MyTestRepo\\Data\\RemoteGitRepo.git
```

Not sure if I am missing something here. Please advice..

Comment: `Fetch()` accepts some callbacks to provide the user with feedback regarding the current operation. Can you implement them, output to the Console what they return then update the question with the results?

Comment: This error message originates back from **[here](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/03c28d92d00074f1501cb0d7ce9f5e3e0154a244/src/refs.c)**. It looks like `git_remote_update_tips()` tries to make the remote tracking heads point to non existing objects. Weird thing is that those objects are supposed to have already been retrieved by the `Fetch()` process.

Comment: @nulltoken: None of the callbacks gets Invoked... Error is thrown @ `int res = NativeMethods.git_remote_update_tips(remote);`

Comment: Please post end to end repro code

Comment: @nulltoken: I guess, I found the issue. The `libgit2sharp` `fetch` fails if the  local repo is a `bare` repository. It works fine with git.exe..

Comment: I have filed an issue [here](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/426)